# How can I Specify MOXy JAXB as my Apache CXF implementation for Apache CXF 2.2.6

Tags: java, cxf, eclipselink, moxy

How can I tell Apache CXF to use MOXy JAXB?

Comment: Are you creating a JAX-WS or a JAX-RS service?

Comment: Yes I am using JAX-RS.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `jaxb.properties` file with your domain classes: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: It seems to me that Apache CXF uses org.apache.cxf.databinding.JAXBDataBinding class as the primary means of allowing potential overrides. I saw your solution titled "Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as Your JAXB Provider". It seems if I understand it right, that I might have to put this properties file in every package that has a JAXB class. Is that a correct assumption? Not all the JAXB classes are in the same package. It also seems I might have to handle the marshalling and unmarshalling myself, from looking at your example

Comment: aside: You may want to consider using a newer release of CXF (2.5+) as the 2.2.x line is no longer being maintained. See http://cxf.apache.org/roadmap.html

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

For  JAX-RS applications in Apache CXF it may be enough to add a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as your domain model specifying MOXy as the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html) with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

This is all that is required when creating a JAX-RS application using [**Jersey**](http://jersey.java.net/).

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

> It seems to me that Apache CXF uses
>   org.apache.cxf.databinding.JAXBDataBinding class as the primary means
>   of allowing potential overrides. I saw your solution titled
>   "Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as Your JAXB Provider". It seems if I
>   understand it right, that I might have to put this properties file in
>   every package that has a JAXB class. Is that a correct assumption?

The `jaxb.propertie` file needs to be in at least one of the packages used to create the `JAXBContext`.

**Coming in EclipseLink 2.5**

Similar to the `MOXyJsonProvider` class we added in EclipseLink 2.4 to make it easy to configure MOXy as your JSON provider (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html), in EclipseLink 2.5 we are adding `MOXyXmlProvider` to make it easy to use MOXy as your XML provider in environments where simply adding the `jaxb.properties` file doesn't work.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/397125